# modify the property value of JSON string stored in the Table Column

Tags: php, mysql, json, sql-update

I have JSON string stored in my database column. I have to update that value in JSON string.

Here Is my table.
[image: my-table-image]

I want to update the `state` value inside it.

#### Example:

> Name1 has State value `KA` so I want to update it to `GJ`.

#### What I have Tried So far?

```
UPDATE Customer
SET Detail = JSON_MODIFY(Detail , '$.Address.State', 'KA')
WHERE Name = 'name1';
```

Also Tried `JSON_REPLACE` is also not working.

#### But it shows the error:

> FUNCTION Customer.JSON_MODIFY **does** not exist

Note: I know one workaround to do this but I didn't Want to fetch that string and update it completely. I want to update the particular detail in string.

I have also created the [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30b536/6)

I am doing this on localhost. Below are the localhost detail.

```
Database server     
Server: localhost (localhost via TCP/IP)
Software: MySQL
MySQL Version :5.5.24

phpMyAdmin
Version information: 3.5.1, latest stable version: 4.7.3
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?.

Comment: I will edit this detail in question @wchiquito

Comment: As wchiquito already told you: json was added in 5.7. You are using 5.5. So all these json function do not work because they do not exist yet. And I don't think there is a json udf that can do this update either (but maybe you are lucky). So either upgrade your mysql server or fetch that string and update it completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [12.16 JSON Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html)
>
> ...
>
> Unless otherwise indicated, the JSON functions were added in MySQL
>   5.7.8.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
UPDATE `Customer`
SET `Detail` = JSON_REPLACE(`Detail`, '$.Address.State', 'GJ')
WHERE `Name` = 'name1';
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/87WqNtwkcx6pMwStoKXCoV/0).

Comment: It will showing `FUNCTION JSON_REPLACE does not exist` in mySql at locahost

Comment: your fiddle is working but it shows error in my localhost.

Comment: @always-a-learner: `JSON_REPLACE` function is available since MySQL version 5.7.8.

Comment: to due all respect sir my sql shows the above mention error. I have tried other json functions but still same erroe shows up. @Wchiquito

Comment: @always-a-learner: I understand that your version of MySQL is 5.5.24, in that version the JSON functions are not available.

Comment: can you tell me what should i do? @Wchiquito

Comment: @always-a-learner: Did you upgrade to the indicated version of MySQL?.

Answer (score 6):

As @wchiquito already pointed out, the JSON function were added in *MySQL 5.7.8*.

If you are not able to upgrade your MySQL installation you will have to take the workaround you mentioned. Using regular expression to replace your value is also not going to work without being able to define custom mysql functions. *(Also there is a lot that can go wrong if you do operations like this with regex...)*

So the only options I see you have, are:

1. **upgrade** your installation (award to @wchiquito).
2. Fetch the column, parse it and update it. Just as you mentioned yourself as a workaround.

That could look something like this:

```
// fetch the details
$sth = $pdo->prepare('select `Detail` from `Customer` where `Name` = ?');
$sth->execute(['name1']);

$detail = json_decode($sth->fetchColumn(), true);

// modify the state
$detail['Address']['State'] = 'KA';

// update the details
$sth = $pdo->prepare('update `Customer` set `Detail` = ? where `Name` = ?');
$sth->execute([json_encode($detail), 'name1']);
```

But I recommend just upgrading your MySQL installation if possible.

Answer (score 1):

As you have an old MySQL, fetch the JSON string, decode it to an array, edit the array, re-encode it, and update your row:

```
// Fetch row
$json = $row['columnName'];
$array = json_decode($json, true); //true creates array and not stdClass
$array['valueToChange'] = 'some new value';
$json = json_encode($array);
// Perform update query
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

Use **JSON_INSERT** function to add the property to the object if it is not exist

Use **JSON_REPLACE** function substitutes the property only if it is exist

Use **JSON_SET** function to add the property if it is not found then replace it.

Hope this helps!